# how to save keystroke output in AppleScript variable?

Tags: bash, shell, testing, applescript

I have written an AppleScript that starts my shell by typing in the commands in the terminal. But I want to test the shell and so I want to save the command result in a variable. This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
osascript <<EOF
tell application "System Events"
  keystroke "cd /Users/uwe/documents/coding/c/pshell"
  delay 0.5
  keystroke return
  delay 0.5
  keystroke "make compile_and_run"
  delay 1
  keystroke return
  delay 0.5
  keystroke "bash /Users/uwe/documents/coding/c/pshell/tests/user_test.sh"
  delay 0.5
  keystroke return
  key code 126
  delay 0.5
  set arrow_result to keystroke return // this is where I want to save the output
  display dialog arrow_result // it says there is no variable called 'arrow_result'
end tell
EOF
```

If its possible I could also store the result in a bash variable but I don't think that  that works

Comment: Maybe you could save the script's output in a file (`bash .../user_test.sh > /tmp/scriptoutput`) and display the file's content from inside osascript, but without knowing what `user_test.sh` does, I cannot say for sure. It is unclear **what** output you want to capture and **where it comes from** (`user_test.sh` or `System Events` itself?). Either way: Doing everything in bash except for the `display dialog` part is probably better.

Comment: The Terminal is also scriptable.

Comment: @Socowi maybe the script is the wrong example I want to type a command in the shell with `keystroke` and whatever the output to that command is I want to save. So lets say I type `ls` then I want the current files/dirs to be saved to a variable that I can compare to other variables.

Comment: @red_menace what are you trying to say

Comment: Yes, the ``key code 126`` confused me. Your comment cleared this up. Have you tried [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/192632)?

Comment: @Socowi In my understanding they pass the "$1" as an argument to another script but it's not mentioned how to actually receive the data in "$1" in the first place

Comment: If you are scripting the **Terminal**, the entire history buffer of the window/tab is available to the script, so you can just look where you are before the command, and get the stuff immediately after.  There is also `do script` that can be used instead of the **System Events** stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can of course send **keystroke** commands and then get the text content of the terminal window (and then parse it) with the following command:

```
set arrow_result to value of text field 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of window 1 of process "Terminal"
```

But why be so perverted. There is no need to use Terminal, System Events and GUI scripting to complete your task. Instead, use the most powerful tool in the AppleScript language, the **do shell script** command:

```
#!/bin/bash
osascript <<EOF
set arrow_result to(do shell script "cd /Users/uwe/documents/coding/c/pshell
  make compile_and_run
  bash /Users/uwe/documents/coding/c/pshell/tests/user_test.sh")
  display dialog arrow_result
EOF
```

NOTE: I tested my suggestion in the Terminal with following code:

```
osascript <<EOF
set arrow_result to do shell script "echo \"Hello, World!\""
display dialog arrow_result
EOF
```

Comment: Seems a bit redundant to use a shell script to run an AppleScript to run a shell script.

Comment: It isn't redundant. I don't remember exactly what the advantage of this approach is. Something associated with the execution of the entire process in the same thread. Here, for example we have background process, which is able display dialog on the front.

Comment: @RobertKniazidis When I try your first solution I get a syntax error saying that it expected an end-of-line but got "end tell". So I remove end tell and it seems as if it puts me in an infinite loop. Any idea what might cause this?

Comment: also I dont think I can have shell scripts execute commands in my custom shell

Comment: I remove **end tell** from my suggestion. It was just typo. Other point: if your **bash /Users/uwe/documents/coding/c/pshell/tests/user_test.sh"** doesn't return some text result, then nothing exist to display. I don't know how your shell scripts is written, and what results they return when executing in the terminal. This is a reason I provide simpified example to test.

Comment: I assume the result of your shell script returns some text, because in the question you try to display it using **display dialog**. If the result is missing, or not textual, then it isn't my fault.